# subsetting data with rows that contain a certain string in r

Tags: r, string

I want to subset my data where the name ends in string TRUST, LIMITED, INC., CO

the data looks like this

```
name            date
abc TRUST       2018-01-01
123 Foundation  1997-02-06
Tim LIMITED     2002-06-04
SA INC.         1968-12-28
Yu Co           2005-01-24
Coca Cola Ltd.  1980-05-30
```

I have tried the following but it is not working for multiple conditions

```
df[grepl(paste0(c("TRUST", "LIMITED", "INC", "CO"), collapse = "|"), df$name), ]
```

It also extracts the coca cola company row as well but I do not want that.

Comment: Could you please also provide your data with `dput`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df[grepl(paste0(c("TRUST", "LIMITED", "INC"), collapse = "|"), df$name), ]

         name       date
1   abc TRUST 2018-01-01
3 Tim LIMITED 2002-06-04
4     SA INC. 1968-12-28
```

The same with `str_detect()`:

```
df %>%
 filter(str_detect(name, paste0(c("TRUST", "LIMITED", "INC"), collapse = "|")))
```