# subsetting data with rows that end in a certain string for a column in r

Tags: r, string, subset

I want to subset my data where the name ends in string TRUST, LIMITED, INC., CO
the data looks like this

```
name            date
abc TRUST       2018-01-01
123 Foundation  1997-02-06
Tim LIMITED     2002-06-04
SA INC.         1968-12-28
Yu Co           2005-01-24
Coca Cola Ltd.  1980-05-30
```

I have tried the following but it is not working for multiple conditions

```
df[grepl(paste0(c("TRUST", "LIMITED", "INC", "CO"), collapse = "|"), df$name), ]
```

It also extracts the coca cola company row as well but I do not want that.

Comment: Haven't you asked the same Question 4 days ago? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57731094/10488504

Comment: The question you posted a few days ago, flagged as a dupe, has an answer already. If that answer isn't satisfactory, there are [things you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) besides just posting the same question again

Answer (score 4):

To find names ending with the given strings you have to place a `$` at the end of your search string.

```
df[grep("(TRUST|LIMITED|INC\\.|Co)$", df$name), ]
#         name       date
#1   abc TRUST 2018-01-01
#3 Tim LIMITED 2002-06-04
#4     SA INC. 1968-12-28
#5       Yu Co 2005-01-24
```

If you are looking for a solution for word ends you can use `\\b` as @akrun already mentioned.

```
df[grep("(TRUST|LIMITED|INC\\.|Co)\\b", df$name), ]
#         name       date
#1   abc TRUST 2018-01-01
#3 Tim LIMITED 2002-06-04
#4     SA INC. 1968-12-28
#5       Yu Co 2005-01-24
```

Answer (score 3):

We need the word boundary (`\\b`) to avoid any non-specific matches.  Also, if we want to match `Co` as well, use the `ignore.case = TRUE`

```
df[grepl(paste0("\\b(", paste(c("TRUST", "LIMITED", "INC", "CO"), 
                 collapse = "|"), ")\\b"), df$name, ignore.case = TRUE), ]
#       name       date
#1   abc TRUST 2018-01-01
#3 Tim LIMITED 2002-06-04
#4     SA INC. 1968-12-28
#5       Yu Co 2005-01-24
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("abc TRUST", "123 Foundation", "Tim LIMITED", 
"SA INC.", "Yu Co", "Coca Cola Ltd."), date = c("2018-01-01", 
"1997-02-06", "2002-06-04", "1968-12-28", "2005-01-24", "1980-05-30"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```